# How can I insert a new line with sed that will allow a backslash in the entry

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have a file that contains users.  The format of the file is as follows:

```
groupname:
username \
username2 \
username3 \
```

and so on.

I am automating a portion of adding users to this file.  I am currently using sed to complete this, but I am running into an issue.  Here is what I am using for my sed command

```
sed -i '/groupname/ a\'newuser' \ \' /path/to/file
```

My problem is that the above command will enter a space after the backslash, which, for unknown reasons causes the application that utilizes this file to cease working.

I tried using the following with no positive results

```
sed -i '/groupname/ a\'newuser' \\' /path/to/file
sed -i '/groupname/ a\'newuser \'\ /path/to/file
sed -i '/groupname/ a\"newuser \"\ /path/to/file
sed -i '/groupname/ a\'newuser' "\"\ /path/to/file
```

My next step I think might be ritual sacrifice, but, I would prefer not to have to go that route.

I did try one thing with awk, but, I am less familiar with that.

```
awk '{print} /groupname/{print "newuser \"}' /path/to/file
```

That is met with an error message about an unterminated string starting at the " for "testing

Any suggestions would be met with much enthusiasm until such a point ritual sacrifice might actually become a reality, then its just sad faces all around.

Thanks in advance.

[edit]

For clarification, this command is being run from another server via ssh.  So the command that executes from server A is as follows:

```
ssh serverb "sudo sed -i '/groupname/ a\'newuser' \ \" /path/to/file
```

That command works to the extent it inserts the extra space after the "\" which I don't need.

Comment: `\ ` is an escape char so in the awk script `\"` is escaping the double quote. To get a literal `\ ` you need to escape it with a second `\ `, i.e. `print "newuser \\"`.

Comment: By the way - wrt `a space after the backslash, which, for unknown reasons causes the application that utilizes this file to cease working.`. Think about it for a sec. A backslash followed by a space is an escaped space, NOT an escaped newline, so the result is not a continued line as you'd get with an escape before a newline, it's a terminated line where the last char is a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
sed -i "/groupname/ a\'newuser' \\ \\" /path/to/file
```

Comment: I modified this slightly to fit my needs.  I neded up using `sed -i '/groupname/ a\'username' \\\' /path/to/file` and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/groupname/ a\newuser \\' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work with any sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(groupname:\)/&\
newuser \\/' file
groupname:
newuser \
username \
username2 \
username3 \
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `sed's` job but here is an `awk` option:

```
awk -v t='newuser \' '/groupname/{print $0 ORS t;next}1' /path/to/file
```

you can set whatever text you want in an `awk` variable (here `t`).

or, if you prefer to hardcode then:

```
awk '/groupname/{print $0 ORS "newuser \\";next}1' /path/to/file
```

Comment: Your hardcode option is working for me.  How do I make this change permanent with awk?  I know with sed I would just use -i, but not sure what needs to be done with awk.

Comment: @JosephDevaney Thanks for the feedback. With `GNU awk` version 4.1 you have an option of `inplace` changes. If you don't then the old conventional method would be to do `awk '..' file > tmp && mv tmp file`

Comment: GNU awk 3.1.6.  :\  Server is on a list to be upgraded, but, I have to work with the hand I am dealt for now.  Thanks for the info!